# How to GET number of posts for each category with type category_post using Codeigniter (query group_by )?

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, model-view-controller, eloquent

hello Stackoverflow team, I'm working on a project using Codeigniter and I want to display the following data by showing the number of data in real time.
I have a TABLE named POST which contains id, title, content, category_id
and a TABLE named CATEGORY which contains id, category_name, category_type.
So i would like to display the total of POSTS recorded for each CATEGORY selected in the request, because the CATEGORY table is used for other tables, so I want to have just categories which relates to POSTS, but when i send the data to the view i get the following error :
Severity: Warning

Message: oci_execute(): ORA-00979: not a group by expression GROUP BY.
//UPDATE:!!
So After editing the Model code as suggestedg, i get the following error code
Message: oci_execute(): ORA-00936: missing expression

Maybe I have problem with JOIN and GROUP_BY and also difficulties about how to display data in VIEW
here an image on how I want to have the data,
any help will be appreciated
Thank you for your assistance, my respects
[image: here the result i'm woring on]

here is my Model

```
    class My_model extends CI_Model {
    
        function get_post_by_category() {
            $q = $this->db->select(' POST.CATEGORY_ID, CATEGORY.CATEGORY_NAME, COUNT(POST.CATEGORY_ID) as total_posts,  COUNT(POST.CATEGORY_ID)/COUNT(*) * 100 as percentage')
                          ->from('POST')
                          ->join('CATEGORY', 'POST.CATEGORY_ID= CATEGORY.ID', 'left')
                          ->where('CATEGORY.CATEGORY_TYPE', 'TYPE_POST')
                          ->group_by('POST.CATEGORY_ID, CATEGORY.CATEGORY_NAME') 
                          ->order_by('POST.CATEGORY_ID', 'ASC')
                          ->get();
            return $q->result();
        }
    }
```

here is my controller

```
 public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('My_model');
    }

    function index() {
        $this->load->model('My_model'); 
        //config
        $config['base_url'] = base_url('/?c=ui_page'); 
        //load the method of model  
        $data['countdata']=$this->My_model->get_post_by_category(); 
        //return the data in view  
        $this->load->view('data/my_view', $data);
    }
```

here is my view

```
<table border="1">  
      <tbody>  
         <tr>  
            <td> CATEGORY NAME</td>  
            <td> Total POSTS</td> 
            <td> %</td>  
         </tr>  
         <?php  
         foreach ($countdata as $row1)  
         {  
            ?><tr>  
            <td><?php echo $row1->CATEGORY_NAME;?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $row1->ID;?></td>  
            <td>%</td>  
            </tr>  
         <?php }  
         ?>  
      </tbody>  
   </table>
```

Comment: You are defining CATEGORY twice, in the FROM And JOIN, remove it from the FROM and it should work  *from('POST')  , btw I would never call a table POST as that's a reserved word and can trip you up

Comment: hello thank you for your answer, I appreciate it, I tried but still the same problem

Answer (score 2):

if you not specified columns at `GROUP BY` clause, you cannot use this columns at `SELECT`. Because `GROUP BY` gives array and `SELECT` expects only one element. But you can use aggregate functions such as `COUNT`, `AVG`, `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM` and so on([List of Aggregate functions](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/Aggregate-Functions.htm#SQLRF20035)).

So try this solution:

```
class My_model extends CI_Model {

    function get_post_by_category() {
        $postsCount = $this->db->select('count(*) as posts_count')
                        ->from('POST')->get()->row()->posts_count;
        
        $this->db->select(' POST.CATEGORY_ID, CATEGORY.CATEGORY_NAME, COUNT(POST.CATEGORY_ID) as total_posts')
                ->from('POST')
                ->join('CATEGORY', 'POST.CATEGORY_ID= CATEGORY.ID', 'left')
                ->where('CATEGORY.CATEGORY_TYPE', 'TYPE_POST');
        $this->db->group_by('POST.CATEGORY_ID, CATEGORY.CATEGORY_NAME'); 
        $this->db->order_by('POST.CATEGORY_ID', 'ASC');
        $q = $this->db->get();
        return [ 'result' => $q->result(), 'post_count' => $postsCount ];
    }
}
```

Without changes to your controller, your view must be like:

```
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> CATEGORY NAME</td>
            <td> Total POSTS</td>
            <td> %</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        foreach ($countdata['result'] as $row1) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row1->CATEGORY_NAME; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row1->total_posts; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo  $countdata['post_count'] > 0 ? round(($row1->total_posts / $countdata['post_count']) * 100, 2) : 0; ?>%</td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: hello thank you for your answer, I appreciate it, I have updated the query but i get error ora-00936 missing expression, mybe i have a problem with showing the data throug the view i have updated the question, thank you very much for your support

Comment: Can you merge group_by and order_by to one expression with select ?  example:  $this->db->select()->from.....->db->group_by()->db->order_by()

Comment: Thank you @Orkhan Zeynalli for your answer, I appreciate it, I have updated the query  as suggested but i still get the same error ora-00936 missing expression, mybe it's a problem with the JOIN and GROUP_BY and difficulties with showing the data throug the view i have updated the question, thanks for your support.

Comment: Hi, I'm back the query return the data, so how can i display the count data in view as mentioned in the uploaded image with the question, Big thanks

Comment: Hi @optic4predator1 , I changed answer, added changes to model and view

Comment: Hi @Orkhan Zeynalli thank you for your support, i appreciate it, after editing the code as suggested i had the following Error

Message: Call to a member function row() on array

Comment: It was a mistake at count query builder. I removed result() from the count query builder at model.

Comment: now i get the total for each category but i'm still facing an issue in ROW percentage i get following error
Severity: Warning Message: Division by zero
thank you for your help

Comment: Oh I forgot, posts count may 0 . I have added this condition  to view and updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, indeed I receive a percentage but its value is not correct,, because 100% represents the sum of all POSTS of all CATEGIRIES, while each category has a percentage, which means if we combine the sum of the percentages of each category, the result must equal 100% as shown in the photo example
My respect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247999/discussion-between-optic4predator1-and-orkhan-zeynalli).